# ivy.xml is modified in ivy cache

Tags: ivy

Just discovered strange behavior of Ant Ivy cache and want to ensure that is not a bug but was implemented by intention.

I publish my module to the local repository, then ivy retrieves it to the cache while building another module. Good.

But if you navigate into cache directory (~/.ivy2/cache/[organisation]/[module]/) you'll see two flavors of module's ivy.xml file:

1. ivy-VERSION.xml.original
2. ivy-VERSION.xml

The first one is exactly the same as I have in my repository, while the second is obviously modified. For example it has status="release" (in the repository it is "integration"), publication timestamp is also changed (to the moment cache is updated).

Could somebody confirm this is correct behavior of the cache?

Answer (score 0):

Very late to the party here, but wanted to capture this in case anyone else found this post.

I ran into a similar problem where the ivy.xml file was modified and the configuration information stripped way. Turns out the problem was that I had a period in the configuration description. Changing from "Java 1.7" to "Java 17" solved the problem and stopped the file from being modified.

```
<configurations>
   <conf name="base" description="base dependencies that all configurations rely upon"/>
   <conf name="apilegacy" description="dependencies and publication for the java 15 client" extends="base"/>
   <conf name="api" description="dependencies and publication for the java 17 client" extends="base"/>
```